# meta name="viewport" and @media: activate CSS based upon width of actual page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Edit: found a grave mistake on my part int he code, nothing relevant for others with the same problem, I simply had a missing "}" on a media query above the ones not working.

Please explain like I am 5.

So I am trying to get my [page](http://208.69.30.150/build/index.html) to shuffle around some margins, change some floats and generally be responsive. I can't seem to get it to work. Basically what I want is for the CSS inside a @media query to toggle when the width of the browser window, not the device screen width, hits a certain mark. Right now that is not working. I figured that I'd use the cascading nature of CSS to override the fact that *all* of the @media CSS should be active when below the lowest max-width. This does not seem to be the case, instead I get the CSS from the 1600px one at some much lower resolution.

So I read up, and the more I read the more confused I get. Please help!

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 1600px ) {
    .container .block_people .person{
        margin: 0 0 500px 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1400px ) {
    .block_people .person{
        margin: 0 0 100px 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px ) {
    .block_people .person{
        margin: 0 0 100px 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 0.5%;
    }
    .block_people .person{
        margin: 0 0 100px 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px ) {
    .block_people .person{
        min-width: 300px;
        width: 90%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 150px 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px ) {
    .buttons {
        right: 225px;
    }
     nav.slide-menu-right{
        width: 200px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS looks relatively complex to me. Another way you could write your media queries is below, this approach may help you target styles and viewports more easily:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
}

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px) {
}

@media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
}  
etc
```

If you want to try and get cascading to work, I usually set any default styles then build up from narrow to wide viewports. Doing it this way means that if you have set a style at a narrow viewport, you can easily override it at wider viewports (because the style will be further down the style sheet) e.g.

```
/* start with default styles */  

@media (min-width: 601px ) { .... }  
@media (min-width: 801px ) { .... }  
@media (min-width: 1001px ) { .... }  
@media (min-width: 1201px ) { .... }  
@media (min-width: 1401px ) { .... }
```

Good luck!

Comment: You are indeed right! But setting the same specificity on the next media query does not allow the 1600px one to activate. Instead, just below 1000px, it jumps from no media css to the 1400px css. Looking at where the margin is set in the normal css it looks like this:

.person{
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 200px 0;
   }
So my media CSS should over write it both because of specificity and due to cascading. However setting it to be just .person has the same result.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @IthilonethMoonsnow, please see my edit above, maybe that will simplify things for you

Comment: I found my problem... It is really embarrassing... So I have another media section, pasted for the sake of a plugin I am using. I had missed a closing "}" and this was causing all the other media queries to be enveloped into the one above. Which, surprise surprise, was set to max-width 100px...

Thank you for your help! I will still look at your method. It seems like a good way to create some sure fire media queries!

Comment: good going @IthilonethMoonsnow, it's easy to miss the extra } on media queries. Rereading with brain engaged, I could see that CSS specificity would not cause a problem in this specific case so I've edited my answer to avoid any confusion for others.

Comment: This is great... question, what if I wanted (0 to 319 and 321 to 450) one style and 320 to have another style? What order would I add it to CSS?

Comment: hey @Si8 , see if this helps? https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/rZKqVM It's a shorter solution to achieve what you are describing

Comment: so I can't just use `width: 320px` I have to specify min and max for the width even though it is the same. great. Thanks

Comment: Your suggestion was my first thought as well, I wasn't certain if it was correct though and was unable to find an answer one way or the other. I just thought of a way to confirm and yes it does validate.  I created a new pen at https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/aajKZp and it passes W3C CSS validation, see http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs.codepen.io%2Fpanchroma%2Fdebug%2FaajKZp%2FPBkNWNbKxxKM&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en  . It's getting better all the time @Si8 ;)